# When Lagering outdoors

Tags: lager, lagering

Can you lager outdoors, in the Winter as long as you keep the beer out of the light?
I don't have the means or the containers needed to Lager.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely!

I've got a shed behind my house which I call "the lagering shed".  You should know the range of temperatures which are likely to occur, and keep an eye on your beer.  I live in south-western British Colombia, where winter temperatures are great for outdoor lagering.  We sometimes go a bit below zero, but usually not much below, and usually not for long.

Once I allowed my beer to partly freeze.  Part of the contents of the carboy were in a slush or slurpee form.  As I recall, I brought it in at that point.  Of course you will want to avoid your beer freezing further than this.